# How I parse Following response using Codable?

Tags: json, swift, codable

How to parse the following response using `Codable`

```
{
    "Response": {
        "ResponseStatus": 1,`enter code here`
        "TraceId": "00125bf6-a416-4095-893c-05e05f8c7202",
        "Origin": "BOM",
        "Destination": "PNQ",
        "Results": [
                        [
                            {
                                "IsCouponAppilcable": true,
                                "IsGSTMandatory": false,
                                "AirlineRemark": "AI TEST.",
                            },
                            {
                                "IsCouponAppilcable": true,
                                "IsGSTMandatory": false,
                                "AirlineRemark": "AI TEST.",
                            }
                       ]
                ]
        }
}
```

I want to parse "Results" using `Codable`

I tried this but stuck how to parse "Results"

```swift
struct FlightResponceRequest : Codable {
    var Response : FlightResponce
}

struct FlightResponce : Codable {
    var ResponseStatus : Int?
    var Error : FlightError
    var TraceId : String?
    var Origin : String?
    var Destination : String?
    var Results : [FlightResult]?
}

struct FlightError : Codable {
    var ErrorCode : Int?
    var ErrorMessage : String?
} 

struct FlightResult : Codable {

}
```

Comment: Please make an attempt to solve this yourself first and then we can help you with that if you get stuck.

Comment: Add the code to your question instead of posting it as a comment and explain what the issue is with it,

Comment: Show the code where you use `JSONDecoder()`. Show the error that you catch I guess? Like this code minimum: `do { let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(FlightResponceRequest.self, from: json); print(result) } catch { print("Error: \(error)") }` and ALSO the log in console... It would save us a lot of time, and that's your part to do at least as a developer to catch error, and read them...

Comment: Hi Larme,
do {
                    Flights.sharedInstance.flightObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(FlightResponceRequest.self, from: data)
}


If you check my struct, I haven't written anything in FlightResult?
My question is what I Write In FlightResult to Parse "Result"

Comment: In your response I don't see FlightError field, so try to make it optional

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it like that for response because you have an array inside another array.

```
var Results : [[FlightResult]]?
```

And then parse key/values to your `FlightResult` structure.